# File found and not found at the same time

Tags: linux, terminal

So, either my PC turned into Schrödingers PC, or there something seriously wrong, or I am too dumb to notice some obvious error.

I'm in Linux Mint 17.
I have two terminals open. According to pwd, they are both in the same directory. But, if I want to open a specific file, in one terminal it works, in the other terminal the file is not found.

As I was saying ... WHAT!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I might have solved it.

In Schrödingers Terminal, which says I'm in ~Dokuments/PhD/, I created a test file. In a new terminal, I searched for it, and it was found in ./.local/share/Trash/files/PhD/.

I did delete the folder previously, but replaced it with a newer version. It appears that the deletion somehow took the terminal into the trash, without telling the terminal that it is in the trash. Strange.